# display a varoius input text fileds when choosing a select value wodrpress contactform7 plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contactForm7 Plugin for wordpress , i have a select element which contains (1,2,3,5) values , i would like to dispaly a div bloc ( like below) based on the selected value: if i choose 2 for example , 2 div should be displayed . any suggestion?

```html
<div class="col col-md-6"> 
<label>Prenom :[text* prenom id:prenom]</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/form-drop-down-menus-select-other-and-make-a-textbox-appear/2789/2

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Fields for Contact Form 7  solves the problem well :)